# Do the Properties of Oils Change if They're Cooked?

Tags: oil, nutrient-composition

Someone told me a while ago that if you cook with olive oil (in a curry, for example) that its properties change compared with using it in a cold dish (e.g., salad dressing).

Firstly, is this actually true of olive oil, or any oil, for that matter?  If so, how are things like the vitamins, antioxidants or saturated/unsaturated fat balance of a particular oil changed when it's cooked?

Comment: Sorry, but health benefits of anything are a big offtopic here. You can find some older questions which explain smoking point/pyrolisis of oil, but none of the information will be health related.

Comment: Are you seriously saying health is not considered relevant to cooking on this site?  Why is "nutrition" even a valid tag if it's off-topic?  Is this a wind-up!?

Comment: it is relevant to your cooking decisions, but not accepted on our site. It is such a major off-topic that it has its custom close reason. The reason for it being off topic is that there can be no consensus on nutrition topics, and the whole Stack Exchange network relies on factual information only, not discussion of opinions. The nutrition tag is reserved for nutrition label purposes, such as asking if kale has more Vitamin C than spinach. Such a statement is verifiable by a simple measurement, while alone the definition of the word "healthy" is impossible with any reasonable precision.

Comment: Maybe we should just rename nutrition to nutritional-content and be done with it? But nutrition does say in the tag description "Questions regarding facts about macro-nutrients within foods. Do not use for 'what is healthy' or similar questions, which are off-topic." so it should be clear this isn't a wind-up or something we just came up with.

Comment: The "wind-up" comment was somewhat flippant :)  Then again, you have to admit that the on-hold reason of "Questions on nutrition... are off-topic" doesn't make sense if the "nutrition" tag is valid!  Anyway, I've edited it now to be specific about properties so I hope this complies with your standards.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make an edit. I am reopening the question. I am still afraid that I will have to edit or delete answers which take a position on whether the changes are healthy or not, and simple information on the changes (of the kind "some of the saturated and some of the unsaturated fats will change to a multitude of new compounds") will not be of any help to you. But here it is, do with it whatever you can.

Comment: The "Question on nutrition are off-topic" reason makes perfect sense when we consider that language is ambiguous. The [tag:nutrition] tag covers a very tiny area of the whole area of nutrition, which is an exception to the general off-topic rule. It is just that the language has no word for this subarea, so we are using the best name we could come up with. The rules make perfect sense, they are just easy to misinterpret and we have found no better way to communicate them yet.

Comment: @rumtscho, instead of [nutrition], I propose [properties]

Comment: @BaffledCook this is a terrible tag. People who are thinking of macronutrients may or may not think to call the nutritional content of a dish its "properties". People who are thinking of anything else about a dish - texture, transportability, whatever - will also think that "properties" applies to their case. In the end, the word is way too generic to distinguish between different types of questions.

Comment: @rumtscho understood.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is said specifically about extra virgin olive oil. The reasoning is that extra virgin oil is pressed cold and processed without heating in order to preserve specific flavor profiles in the finished product. Cheaper oils are extracted using heat to maximize extraction, but lose some of these flavors.  Generally heating is discouraged because you're paying a premium for unheated oil, so using it in hot applications would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

These links have a lot of information on them:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_oil

http://www.martinfrost.ws/htmlfiles/oct2008/cooking-oils.html

This link specifically answers - Why it's best not to cook with extra virgin olive oil

http://whfoods.org/genpage.php?tname=dailytip&dbid=261